# Kivy How to add changing Dates in Spinner (Dropdown)

Tags: python, kivy, dropdown, spinner

I need the Spinner Dropdown to have values containing- Present day's Date (whichever day the user is opening the app)...+ the next 10 Dates from the present day.  (Note- It should update automatically)

For example,
if present date is 18/8/2021
I need the dropdown to show:-

---

|       Select Date      ^   |

---

|        18/8/2021           |

|        19/8/2021           |

|        20/8/2021           |

|        21/8/2021           |

|        22/8/2021           |

|        23/8/2021           |

|        24/8/2021           |

|        25/8/2021           |

|        26/8/2021           |

|        27/8/2021           |

|        28/8/2021           |

---

Python Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager


class Main(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass
kv=Builder.load_file("test1.kv")
screen=Manager()
screen.add_widget(Main(name="main"))

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return screen

Test().run()
```

Kv Code:

```
<Main>:
    name: "main"
    Spinner:
        id: date
        text: "Select Date"
        values: ["18/8/2021","19/8/2021"] #generated automatically
        size_hint: (.3,.1)
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
        background_color: "#FFFFFF"
        background_normal: ""
        color: "#000000"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Main(Screen):
    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        self.ids["date"].values = [(datetime.now() + timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y') for i in range(10)]


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("test1.kv")

Test().run()
```

.kv file:

```
<Main>:
    name: "main"
    Spinner:
        id: date
        text: "Select Date"
        size_hint: (.3,.1)
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
        background_color: "#FFFFFF"
        background_normal: ""
        color: "#000000"

<Manager>:

Manager:
    Main:
```

Comment: A little like and an `accept this answer` will be enough. ;)

Comment: I just saw that it was `next` and not `before` days so just need to change the `-` by `+`

Comment: Can u explain "def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):" part a bit... it worked without even specifying it in the kv code?

Comment: Hum, `.kv` file doesn't like dynamic stuff. `on_kv_post` is fired when the visual is applied. It's useful to use `ids` by example, you can't use the `ids` in `__init__` but you can in `on_kv_post`.